# Function calls from data.map are not executed synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call same function from map. Depending upon number of entries function will be called.
Here is my code

```
    getDetails = (inputData) => {
      const data = {
         accountName: "test",
         
       };
     let url = `/rest/jarvis/reports/v1/getData`;
       let thisdata = this;
       post(url, data)
         .then((response) => {
           if (
             response.data &&
             response.data.sb &&
             response.data.sb.length > 0
           ) {
         this.props.bs.betDetails = {
               data: [...response.data.sportsbookBets],
               exportAccesses: response.data.exportAccesses,
             };
             this.props.bs.betDetails.data.map((value, index) => {
               console.log("Index Value --->", index);
               this.getEventDetails(value, index);
             }),
               this.updateReducer({
                 ...this.props.bs,
               });
       }
    }       
    }
    getEventDetails = async (value, index) => {
       let _this = this;
       let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
         console.log("Index Value at the entry--->", index);
      const data = {
         accountName: "test",
         
       };
      let url = `/rest/jarvis/reports/v1/getBetEventData`;
    
         post(url, data).then((response) => {
    if (response.data) {
       console.log("Index Value inside--->", index);
               _this.eventIdIndexMap.set(
                 list.eventId != null
                   ? list.eventId
                   : _this.props.bs.betEventRequest.EventId,
                 index
               );
        _this.props.bs.testEventDetails[
                 _this.eventIdIndexMap.get(
                   list.eventId != null
                     ? list.eventId
                     : _this.props.bs.betEventRequest.EventId
                 )
               ] = _this.props.bs.betEventResponse;
    
    }}}
 await myPromise;
}
```

Here problem I am facing is inside post call of 'getEventDetails' index values are not getting in sequence.
I have used promise await and async but it is not working.
Can someone please tell me how to get it properly ?

Comment: you aren't returning anything from your `map` call.

Comment: Could you change the title to _"Asynchronous function calls from data.map are not executed synchronously"_ and explain in the question why you would expect asynchronous functions to be executed synchronously? `async` is a keyword to mark an asynchronous function and `getEventDetails` is marked.

Comment: You cannot make the code inside map synchronous. One solution would be to create an array of promises and then use Promise.all([]) => then do the actions with the data

Answer (score 0):

`map` calls its callback function without `await`. You can use asynchronous functions in the callback function but they won't be executed in order.

But you can create your own `map` with `await`:

```js
async function map(array, cb) {
    const result = [];
    for (const element of array) {
        result.push(await cb(element));
    }
    return result;
}

async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => {
    console.log(await map([3, 2, 1], async el => { await sleep(el * 100); return 2 * el; }));
})();
```

or create your own `Array.prototype.syncMap`:

```js
Array.prototype.syncMap = async function(cb) {
    const result = [];
    for (const element of this) {
        result.push(await cb(element));
    }
    return result;
}

async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => {
    console.log(await [3, 2, 1].syncMap(async el => { await sleep(el * 100); return 2 * el; }));
})();
```

It looks like you don't even need a result. You can write your own `Array.prototype.syncForEach`:

```js
Array.prototype.syncForEach = async function(cb) {
    for (const element of this) {
        await cb(element);
    }
}

async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

[3, 2, 1].syncForEach(async el => { await sleep(el * 100); console.log(2 * el); });
[30, 20, 10].forEach(async el => { await sleep(el * 10); console.log(2 * el); });
```

As you can see in the output the functions in `syncForEach` are executed in order and the functions in `forEach` are executed out of order.